# Can "pace" be used as a synonym of "walk" in this case?

Tags: word-usage

Example sentence with context:

> He put down his phone on the desk, **paced** to the refrigerator, and pulled out a beer.

Usually, *paced* is used when you're walking restlessly around the room. But sometimes I see the [usage](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22paced%20to%20the%20refrigerator%22&rlz=1C1ASUC_enTW628TW628&oq=%22paced%20to%20the%20refrigerator%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.3979j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) that I describe above. Is that usage correct?

Comment: Did you check the definitions of [*pace*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pace) to see if one of them fits your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pace** is sometimes used as a synonym for walk, particularly in the sense of **walk with determination.** There is nothing odd about the usage.

Comment: Yes. Or, "She had a slow and steady pace." **Gait** is another word with a similar sense.

Comment: @JasonBassford But that usage has to do with speed, which is not indicated in the question example.

Comment: @user3169 You can quickly pace or slowly pace, just as you can quickly walk or slowly walk. Both words can be used—and speed can be applied to both of them. (Although you certainly can't "gait" to the fridge, regardless of speed, so that additional comment of mine was misleading in hindsight.)